# Native Transport Requests All time blocked

Tags: cassandra

Trying to understand more about Native-Transport-Requests!

As we know these are cql requests and if limit exceeds the result will be all time blocked NTR.

My question is how do i monitor these requests in real time and get some kind of report on it.

I see some settings like max_queued_native_transport_requests and native_transport_max_threads. How these settings will have effect over all time blocked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [JIRA-11363](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11363).

Also check this [discussion](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201708.mbox/%3CCA+VSrLoTd8pKBEeVQZoYnDgqkhXvj5YtuFMLKF13vOu+OT9TTQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) for more info.

The recommendation is to start with the default values and tune from there. The default values are:

```
max_queued_native_transport_requests=1024
native_transport_max_threads: 128
```

Monitor you nodes and if you see an increasing number of blocked Native-Transport-Requests, then you need to increase max_queued_native_transport_requests.

Also, I think it's worth checking these discussions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376735/high-native-transport-requests-all-time-blocked), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456843/what-are-native-transport-requests-in-cassandra)

Comment: Thanks for the info. 

Did you ever experience a situation where connection disconnects going into NTR all time blocked? 

Why disconnects are making cql calls ?

Comment: @sandeep No, I did not see this.